¿Como puedo mantener clases cargadas en memoria en java por un slpash screen?
Estoy haciendo un programa en Java, el cual contiene un splash screen con un JProgressbar. el cual conforme va aumentando el porcentaje de la barra de progreso, va cargando las demás clases de mi programa, pero no sé si cuando ese splash screen ejecuta su dispose();
, las demás clases se descarguen de la memoria o no.
Todo esto lo quiero hacer para que el programa "se ejecute mejor y sin tanta espera por parte del usuario", pero no tengo idea de si si funciona o no.
Adjunto el código que hace funcionar al JProgressbar de mi splash screen
    private void barraProgresoIniciado(){
        Timer timer=new Timer(45, (ActionEvent e) -> {//funcion lambda para el timer
           pb_barraCarga.setValue(pb_barraCarga.getValue()+1);//obtiene el valor que ya tiene y le suma 1
           pb_barraCarga.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);//Cambia el color de fondo de la barra de progreso
           pb_barraCarga.setStringPainted(true);//Habilita el poder mostrar texto en la barra de prograso
           pb_barraCarga.setString("Cargando... "+pb_barraCarga.getValue()+"%");//Establece un texto en la barra de progreso
           //esta línea de código son de ejemplo para hacer la carga de las clases
           if(pb_barraCarga.getValue()==1){
              claseACargar ejmplo=new claseACargar();
           }
        });
           
        timer.start();//inicia el timer
    }

Espero que alguien me pueda explicar el como mantener en memoria las demás clases de mi programa, o en su defecto el como mejorar mi programa para que haga lo que quiero (qué la barra de progreso cargue todas las clases y una vez se termine de ejecuta dicha clase de la barra de progreso, las demás clases se mantengan en memoria hasta que se cierre el programa)

Podrias usar el patron singleton y asi asignar la carga de tus elementos

¿podrías mostrarme un ejemplo?

Para que lo pienses de otra forma... una pantalla, no es mas que otra clase... si una clase, carga otras clases... al descargarse esa clase, se pierden las referencias a las otras clases.. no??? Entonces si lo que vos queres es tener un monton de clases, o las cargas y luego le pasas las referencias a otras clases, o cargas esas clases en otro lado que no se pierda al bajar esa pantalla...

mmmm, mira tengo una clase principal qué es la que va a invocar a la clase donde está el slpash screen, para que luego esta cargue las demás clases, pero no se si cuando el splash screen termine de cargar y ejecute el dispose(); se descargaran también las clases qué se cargaron durante su ejecución del splash screen

Puedes crear las... los objetos en la clase MuestraProgreso y una vez terminados, invocar a los setters correspondientes de las clases que los usarán, mientras exista una referencia a un objeto, este se mantiene independientemente de donde se haya creado.
